# coffeescript function not returning jquery heights as integers

Tags: jquery, html, css, coffeescript

When I run this coffeescript code, the result of the alert top2 comes as  "v1 + v2 + v3" when I need the return value to be the actual integer numbers.

I am trying to dynamically set the css top property of #open-nav to $('#top-header').height +  $('#top-nav').height - $(window).scrollTop

```html
    v1 = $('#top-header').height
    v2 = $('#top-nav').height
    v3 = $(window).scrollTop
    top2 = (v1, v2, v3) -> v1 + v2 + v3
        
     
    top2
    $('#open-nav').css 'top': top2
    alert top2
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is that `top2` doing in the third line from the bottom? If you call the function `top2` you should pass all 3 parameters with it. If you don't pass any values for `v1`, `v2` and `v3` there's nothing the function can calculate for you. `height` and `scrollTop` are functions, so you're missing brackets as well. It would also be a good idea to `parseInt` these values because they could carry `px`.